# Windows not booting from GRUB

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

After dual booting Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10  , when I select Windows from GRUB I sometimes boot into Windows perfectly fine . At other times I get a green jagged line screen for 2 mins , to be replaced by the a pink screen .

About half the time I get the jagged lines screen and about half the time Windows loads . Ubuntu however has no problem in loading . 
Please help.

Comment: Have you made any changes to you grub entries ?

Comment: Can you post an image of the pink screen and the green jagged lines?

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) from Ubuntu. This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post it to a [pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more information on your configuration that may be helpful.